# SessionId login failed

Tags: salesforce-id, login-errors

Please correct my understanding
1.The user gives his userName and Password to login to my third party application.
2.A access_token is generated for the login.
3.My app should use this accesss_token as sessionId to communicate to the salesforce server on behalf of my user
Is this understanding correct?
If yes then then this sessionId should be valid for eternity unless there is some action(change or something ) from the user.
Then why am I getting a expired sessionId  error?I genereated this sessionId couple of days back.

Answer (score 0):

You will be following the Web Server Authentication Flow:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm

A salesforce sessionid is different than an access_token, and hence their also is a refresh_token that can be used in the case where the access_token expires. Another resources that gives additional information:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications